# Python Tkinter Clickable Text?

Tags: text, colors, tkinter, click, bind

I'm wondering if there's a way to make clickable text in Tkinter.  Maybe like you would see on a title screen of a game, and where you hover your mouse over the text and it changes color/hightlights itself.  All I need the click to do is execute another function.

Are either of these things possible? Thanks!

Comment: it is called `Button`.  see: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are several ways to make clickable text -- buttons, labels, text on a canvas, text on a text widget.

Comment: Hover detection is also possible, but requires detection of successive states for comparison.

Answer (score 6):

you are looking for tkinter's events:

```
tk_widget.bind("<Button-1>",CALLBACK)
```

The call back needs to take an event argument which is a dictionary containing information about what triggered the event.

This can run into issues with widgets that overlap such as windows in a canvas or labels sometimes triggering the callback for the window behind it.

For hovering the mouse over a widget the event is called `"<Enter>"` and moving mouse out of widget region is called `"<Leave>"` for highlighting text effect, if you just want to capture a click anywhere on a window then on the root call `root.bind_all("<Button-1>",CALLBACK)`

source: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html

example:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

def change_case(event=None):
    new_text = str.swapcase(lab["text"])
    lab.config(text=new_text)

def red_text(event=None):
    lab.config(fg="red")

def black_text(event=None):
    lab.config(fg="black")

root = tk.Tk()

lab = tk.Label(root,text="this is a test")

lab.bind("<Button-1>",change_case)
lab.bind("<Enter>",red_text)
lab.bind("<Leave>",black_text)

lab.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

hope this helps :)